# How to allow the 32b OPC DA server to be connected from the 64b client over DCOM?

Tags: dcom, opc-da

An existing 32b OPC DA client is able to connect to the remote 32b sever over DCOM. I need to utilize this client in the 64b environment to connect to this server. When the client is built as 64b app, connection is failed with "CoCreateInstanceEx: Class not registered" error when creating server's instance. In the same time the server shows the single client connected, but no client information. This connection disappears after ~7 min as usually for abandoned connection.

What is necessary to do to allow such connection?

The code is simple, just to be here:

```
_server = new Opc.Da.Server(new OpcCom.Factory(), new URL("opcda://" + servername));
_server.Connect(new ConnectData(null, null)); // failed here in the 64b mode.
...
```

OPC Foundation .NET wrapper is in use.

I extensively researched Internet but haven't found the way. The server registration records are available in both 64b and 32b branches of the registry.

Comment: As per now, I resolved this problem using .NET Remoting, but the solution will be interesting in any way. I'm going to create openHistorian OPC DA Input Adapter and then publish it.